# making currency detection app showing using flutter and dart showing error

Tags: flutter, dart, compilation, package, tensorflow-lite

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

please help me to fix this problem in flutter  , I am continuously trying to fix this issue last one weak

I have already try

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.